# Angular Drag and Drop with Layout Option

Tags: angular, layout, drag-and-drop, draggable

I am using angular material cdk for drag and drop feature.

But there are no restrictions for arrangements. (Drag and Drop Field-Side by Side like a grid)

[image]
Can i set layout option and allow drag and drop elements on that layout area.?

Can we make this on the fly so that user can set his layout and drag the required fiels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to catch the object when it gets inside the layout with the methods of the drag and drop. Then you may use an *ngFor and bootstrap for making the grid you want. I can make an example later today so may see what im talking about.

And there is the option to drag and drop inside that area also, it will update the array of objects, you can negate the change of the objects with a checkbox if you want.

Edit2:

here is the Stackblitz url: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-kwbp3q you can toggle the grid with an ngIf so it works properly

Comment: yeap let me prepare you a Stackblitz

Comment: I added the stackblitz, please tell me if thats what you were expecting

Comment: Nice, right now you are keeping the fields 2 columns per row. in some cases i may have 2 columns, in some cases, i have have 1 column, where to define that can you please guide me.

Comment: I was somewhat stuck with that, but I just found out the solution, I'll update the stackblitz in a few seconds, hope that approach works for you